# The “action description” for a proposed change is incorrect sometimes

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

If I edit to change a topic’s versions from “All Versions” to some (but not all) of the versions:
[image: Remove “All Versions;” Add “iPhone OS 3—iOS 9”]

the “action description” of the edit changes:
[image: added 7 versions]
I would expect this to say something like “removed 1 version.” This is because the topic was formerly valid for all versions, and is now valid for all versions **except** “iPhone OS 2.”
<sub><sup>**Note**: I’m making this example up; the topic probably is valid for all versions.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we do now is a delta on all *explicitly specified* versions, inline and not.

Let's look at an example. Let's say a topic applies to "all versions", has a Remarks section that has two version blocks: one for all versions < 4.0, the other for all versions >= 4.0. Let's say the version list is `1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0`. If I edit this topic and replace "all versions" with just `1.0, 2.0, 4.0`, the edit summary will say "added 2 versions" - this covers the explicit addition of 1.0 and 2.0, since 4.0 was already accounted for in the Remarks.

I'm... honestly not sure if that entirely makes sense. It does produce odd-looking results, as you report, but it's at least easy to explain, so I think I could go either way here. A fix trying to account for all possible scenarios would most certainly involve complicating the summary logic, so I'm inclined to stick with what we have, but I'm open to counter-arguments. I'll see what the team thinks internally as well.

**Update:** we discussed this internally and decided to just side-step the entire issue. Starting with the next build, the change summary will say "edited versions" and we'll rely on diffs to provide the details.